# Spring Boot override interface in test

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot

I have a springboot app (v1.3.5)

My main application goes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.akrome"})
public class InboxCoreApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InboxCoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Somewhere in the packages I have a repo defined as an implementation:

```
@Repository
public class CouchbaseServiceImpl implements CouchbaseService {
```

And somewhere else I have a class using that interface:

```
@Repository
public class InboxObjectRepositoryImpl {
    @Autowired
    private CouchbaseService couchbaseService;
```

I also have a test version of the interface:

```
@Repository
public class CouchbaseServiceTestImpl implements CouchbaseService {
```

Now. In my test, I want to simply re-point the interface mapping to the test implementation, while keeping everything else as defined by the main config component scan. But it keeps going bananas. The closest I got is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {InboxCoreApplication.class, TestConfig.class})
public class InboxServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    CouchbaseServiceTestImpl couchBaseServiceTestImpl;
```

Where TestConfig is:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
    CouchbaseServiceTestImpl couchbaseServiceTestImpl = new CouchbaseServiceTestImpl();

    public CouchbaseService couchbaseService() {
        return couchbaseServiceTestImpl;
    }
}
```

But every time either it complains about duplicated bean (bc it sees both implementations), or it injects 2 different instances of the test implementation, one in the test class and one in the actual program (wat?).

Any suggestion?

Comment: can you add the stack trace here?

Comment: Makes sense, you have both `CouchbaseServiceTestImpl` and CouchbaseServiceImpl` which are both loaded by the Spring container for your test. One is loaded due to `TestConfig`, the other one due to you importing the `InboxCoreApplication`, which automatically does a component scan for every subpackage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it.

It's supposed to user profiles:

```
@Repository
@Profile("application")
public class CouchbaseServiceImpl implements CouchbaseService {
```

and

```
@Repository
@Profile("test")
public class CouchbaseServiceTestImpl implements CouchbaseService {
```

and in my test I simply:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {InboxCoreApplication.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class InboxObjectRepositoryImplTest {
```

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is with following class. why are you re-implement the CouchbaseService interface and make it as a test version. What is the real point of doing that? you Unit test class should be developed to test the functionality of your main source.  you are creating a test version of that source class and create a unit test to test that test version. What is the point of doing that?

```
@Repository
public class CouchbaseServiceTestImpl implements CouchbaseService {
```

So the better implementation should be, remove the CouchbaseServiceTestImpl class. write the unit test to directly Test the CouchbaseServiceImpl. (you can remove the TestConfig class also)

so the code should be like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {InboxCoreApplication.class})
public class InboxServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    CouchbaseServiceImpl  couchbaseServiceImpl ;
```

The real reason behind the complaining about the duplicated bean can be described as follows.

If you annotated any class with @Repository, @Component or @Service, the spring IOC container will automatically instantiate those classes and register then in the application context when the Spring application context is loaded.

So you have two implementation of the CouchbaseService  interface.
1. CouchbaseServiceImpl 
2. CouchbaseServiceTestImpl

since both of these classes have been annotated with @Repository, the spring application container will instantiate both of these classes and will maintain both of those objects in the IOC container. both these instance can be assigned to CouchbaseService interface reference.

look at the following line in your code.

```
  @Autowired
  private CouchbaseService couchbaseService;
```

Now the spring application container is in a doubtful situation to find out the relevant matching bean( whether it should use CouchbaseServiceImpl or CouchbaseServiceTestImpl. both of the beans are eligible for the assignment). Therefore it warns about the duplicate and does not do the assignment.

You have two options.

## option 01.

remove the @Repository annotation in one of those classes. preferably remov it in CouchbaseServiceTestImpl. (better to remove that class as i have explained earlier)

## option 02

keep all the classes as you wanted. user @Qualifier to tell the spring application container about the real matching bean for the assignment.

so the code should be changed as follows.

```
@Repository("couchbaseServiceTestImpl")
public class CouchbaseServiceTestImpl implements CouchbaseService {
```

---

```
@Repository("couchbaseServiceImpl")
public class CouchbaseServiceImpl implements CouchbaseService {
```

---

```
@Repository
public class InboxObjectRepositoryImpl {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("couchbaseServiceTestImpl")
    private CouchbaseService couchbaseService;
```

So it is going to assign an instance of CouchbaseServiceTestImpl to CouchbaseService reference.

Comment: The reason is because that's not what I'm testing. That is a DB connection object, when I'm testing the rest of the application I don't want to connect to a DB, just use an in memory mock. But I see your points

Comment: This does not help me though, because the other classes where the bean is injected into won't be able to use this, as they are used the non-test named version :/